# Merge data.frames by different column names and return BOTH columns used for matching

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr

Super simple stupid. 
I'm building a shiny app and comparing column names from two tables. I'm selecting from information.schema and people are going to want to see BOTH of the columns used in the joins

```
 X<-data.frame(table1=c("col1","col2"),types1=c("int","char(4)"))
 Y<-data.frame(table2=c("col2","col3"),types2=c("char(8)","tinyint"))
```

No matter whether I `merge` and use `all=TRUE` or run `dplyr` commands like `left_join` or `full_join`, every single one of these things is giving me an output that looks like:

```
    table1   types1   types2
    col1     int      NA
    col2     char(4)  char(8)
    col3     NA       tinyint
```

I want the columns back. I want this:

```
    table1   table2   types1   types2
    col1     NA       int      NA
    col2     col2     char(4)  char(8)
    NA       col3     NA       tinyint
```

I don't want a collapsed version of the column names in one column. I want to keep the columns in a human readable form so that they know what is missing from where.

Comment: This is just an idea...Maybe you can sort them by `table1` and `table2` and just `cbind(x, y )` ??

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a common column ('grp') by extracting the number from 'table1/table2' in 'X' and 'Y' datasets and then join on that variable

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
X %>% 
   mutate(grp = parse_number(as.character(table1))) %>% 
   full_join(Y %>%
             mutate(grp = parse_number(as.character(table2)))) %>%
   select(starts_with('table'), starts_with('types'))
#  table1 table2  types1  types2
#1   col1   <NA>     int    <NA>
#2   col2   col2 char(4) char(8)
#3   <NA>   col3    <NA> tinyint
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but I have a workaround... even though it would be nice to add an argument to the function.

```
    Y$join<-Y[,"table2"]
    JoinedTable<-merge(X,Y,by.x="table1",by.y="join",all=TRUE)
    JoinedTable[,1]<-ifelse(is.na(JoinedTable[,2]),NA,JoinedTable[,1])
```